# Adding JDBC dependency causes all artifacts to go missing

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have 6 or so maven dependencies successfully built in my project. When I try to add a JDBC dependency however, I get errors for all existing artifacts saying:

Missing artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6

Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE

Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE

Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE

Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE

Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE

Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE

**Here is the dedpendency I am trying to add:** (It looks like valid XML)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Valid Pom.xml Before:**
[image: Valid Pom.xml]

**Error in Pom.xml After adding JDBC dependency:**
[image: Error in Pom.xml]

I've checked and according to the Maven site, 4.3.10.RELEASE is a valid release.

Does anyone know why adding this one dependency causes the entire Pom.xml to error out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had a typo in my `{User_Home}/.m2/settings.xml` file. This was causing new maven build to all fail when updated as the settings file was unreadable.

Comment: Glad you found that. I sometime see eclipse freak out after changing Maven dependencies. For example, I may be able to run a maven install from the command line, but eclipse will mark some classes with compile errors. When this happens, usually cleaning the eclipse project and rebuilding in eclipse will resolve the issue.